# hibernate criteria query for timestamp

Tags: java, hibernate, timestamp, criteria

I have one table which has a column submitted_date(time-stamp without timezone). I need to list all records in the table having a particular date as submitted date. But do not consider the time in database. I retrieve the records by using criteria query and hibernate. How to ignore the time here?

Actually I pass a date from client side and has to retrieve the records that have the same date as submitted_date. But no need to consider the time.

```
    else if(extjsFilter.getField().equals("submittedDate")) {
                            String str_date=extjsFilter.getValue(); 
                            SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                            SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            Date date2 = format1.parse(str_date);
                            String datenew = format2.format(date2);
                            Date date = (Date)format2.parse(datenew);

                            if(extjsFilter.getType().equals("date"))
                            {
                                if(extjsFilter.getComparison().equals("gt"))
                                {
                                    Filter postDateFilterGT = getSession().enableFilter("jobFilterPostDateGT");
                                    postDateFilterGT.setParameter("postDateFilterGT", date);
                                }
                                if(extjsFilter.getComparison().equals("lt"))
                                {
                                    Filter postDateFilterLT = getSession().enableFilter("jobFilterPostDateLT");
                                    postDateFilterLT.setParameter("postDateFilterLT", date);
                                }
                                if(extjsFilter.getComparison().equals("eq"))
                                {
                                    Filter postDateFilterEQ = getSession().enableFilter("jobFilterPostDateEQ");
                                    postDateFilterEQ.setParameter("postDateFilterEQ", date);
                                }
                            }
}
```

Above is my code. Client side is done using extjs. The server side code of extjs filtering for one date field is this.

hibernate is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.hiringsteps.ats.job.domain">
    <class
        name="Job"
        table="hs_job_master"> 

        <id name="id" column="job_id" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">hs_job_id_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="submittedDate" column="submitted_date"/>                

        <filter name="jobFilterPostDateGT"><![CDATA[submitted_date > :postDateFilterGT]]></filter>
        <filter name="jobFilterPostDateLT"><![CDATA[submitted_date < :postDateFilterLT]]></filter>
        <filter name="jobFilterPostDateEQ"><![CDATA[:postDateFilterEQ = submitted_date]]></filter>  
    </class>    

    <filter-def name="jobFilterPostDateGT">
        <filter-param name="postDateFilterGT" type="date"/>
    </filter-def>
    <filter-def name="jobFilterPostDateLT">
        <filter-param name="postDateFilterLT" type="date"/>
    </filter-def>
    <filter-def name="jobFilterPostDateEQ">
        <filter-param name="postDateFilterEQ" type="date"/>
    </filter-def>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have two records in database having submitted_date as below.

2013-02-15 00:00:00

2013-02-15 13:04:42.787

When I make a query to filter records having date as today, the first record with submitted date 
2013-02-15 00:00:00 is only retrieved.

this is because the date object I used to query, has also this value 
'2013-02-15 00:00:00'

How will I make a query which will ignore the time part?

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by 'But do not consider the time in database'?

Comment: waht have you tried yet. your question does not clear

Comment: No need to consider time of what? The system time or db time? Time of execution?

Comment: updated the question once more

Comment: i have facing same problem i have to solve it, find the next day of the given date and fetch the data  GE startDate And LT endDate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, you will have to apply a restriction that selects all dates between submittedDate and submittedDate+1.

```
//Resticts the dates between start date 0000 hrs and end date 0000 hrs
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("startDate", sDate)); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("endDate", eDate));
```

In your case, startDate = 2013-02-15
and end date = 2013-02-16

Comment: I am using hibernate filter. how will I do it with filter?

Comment: i have same problem and i have to solve it with same logic find the next day and fetch the record GE 'date' and LT 'nextdate'

Answer (score 5):

You can try below code, which utilizes native Oracle `trunc` function to discard time while comparison.

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("trunc(submitted_date) = ?", submittedDate, org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.DATE));
```

You can modify the function according to the database provider.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a restriction  to your criteria for property corresponding to column submitted_date. You can write it as

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("submittedDate"), '2013-02-15');
```

Comment: The date parameter should be the one with which you want to compare your time.

Comment: I updated the question once more. could you please look into it