# hibernate filter for date part only

Tags: java, hibernate-filters

Given my hibernate file below. The submitted_date column is a time-stamp without timezone type. Is it possible to set filter that only take the date portion of the column value as a date object or as a string.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.hiringsteps.ats.job.domain">
    <class
        name="Job"
        table="hs_job_master"> 

        <id name="id" column="job_id" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">hs_job_id_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="submittedDate" column="submitted_date"/>                

        <filter name="jobFilterPostDateEQ"><![CDATA[:postDateFilterEQ = submitted_date]]></filter>  
    </class>    

    <filter-def name="jobFilterPostDateEQ">
        <filter-param name="postDateFilterEQ" type="date"/>
    </filter-def>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: What is your program for? insert or fetch?

Comment: not insert. just fetch

Comment: These might help. [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969943/compare-dates-date-part-only-with-timestamp-in-hibernate) [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889741/hibernate-criteria-query-for-timestamp)